# Laravel/Socialite: Class Laravel\Socialite\Contracts\Factory does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-socialite

I'm trying to implement socialite but I am getting an error relating to the Factory class. My app can not find it.

This is the code in my controller:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;

use Laravel\Socialite\Contracts\Factory as Socialite;

class PortalController extends Controller
{

    public function __construct(Socialite $socialite){
           $this->socialite = $socialite;
       }


    public function getSocialAuth($provider=null)
    {
       if(!config("services.$provider")) abort('404'); //just to handle providers that doesn't exist

       return $this->socialite->with($provider)->redirect();
    }


    public function getSocialAuthCallback($provider=null)
    {
       if($user = $this->socialite->with($provider)->user()){
          dd($user);
       }else{
          return 'something went wrong';
       }
    }
```

I added:

`Laravel\Socialite\SocialiteServiceProvider::class,` to providers and

`'Socialite' => Laravel\Socialite\Facades\Socialite::class` to aliases

and my routes looks like

```
Route::get('/portal/{provider?}',[
        'uses' => 'PortalController@getSocialAuth',
        'as'   => 'portal.getSocialAuth'
    ]);


    Route::get('/portal/callback/{provider?}',[
        'uses' => 'PortalController@getSocialAuthCallback',
        'as'   => 'portal.getSocialAuthCallback'
    ]);
```

The error I receive is:

ReflectionException in Container.php line 798:
Class Laravel\Socialite\Contracts\Factory does not exist

Answer (score 3):

I also came across this issue in `Laravel 5.5` **while creating custom oAuth provider**. After Long research I achieved by creating custom `MySocialServiceProvider` class whcih is need to extend by `Laravel\Socialite\SocialiteServiceProvider`. Please go through all the following code and setup with appropriate config, surely it will work.

**My Directory structure as following in the image** 
[image]

**MySocialServiceProvider.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Laravel\Socialite\SocialiteServiceProvider;

class MySocialServiceProvider extends SocialiteServiceProvider
{
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bind('Laravel\Socialite\Contracts\Factory', function ($app) {
            return new MySocialManager($app);
        });
    }
}
```

We have to create a Manger class which will contain as follows

**MySocialManager.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use App\Auth\SocialiteFooDriver;
use Laravel\Socialite\SocialiteManager;

class MySocialManager extends SocialiteManager
{
    protected function createFooDriver()
    {
        $config = $this->app['config']['services.foo'];

        return $this->buildProvider(
            SocialiteFooDriver::class, $config
        );
    }
}
```

We should create a Custom Driver which used by `MySocialManger`

**SocialiteFooDriver.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Auth;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Arr;
use Laravel\Socialite\Two\AbstractProvider;
use Laravel\Socialite\Two\ProviderInterface;
use Laravel\Socialite\Two\User;

class SocialiteFooDriver extends AbstractProvider implements ProviderInterface
{
    /**
     * Foo API endpoint.
     *
     * @var string
     */
//    protected $apiUrl = 'https://auth.foobar.com';
    protected $apiUrl = '';

    public function __construct(Request $request, $clientId, $clientSecret, $redirectUrl)
    {
        parent::__construct($request, $clientId, $clientSecret, $redirectUrl);
        $this->apiUrl = config('services.foo.url');
    }

    /**
     * The scopes being requested.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $scopes = ['openid email profile user_role user_full_name'];

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected function getAuthUrl($state)
    {
        return $this->buildAuthUrlFromBase($this->apiUrl.'/oauth2/authorize', $state);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected function getTokenUrl()
    {
        return $this->apiUrl.'/oauth2/token';
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected function getUserByToken($token)
    {
        $userUrl = $this->apiUrl.'/oauth2/UserInfo?access_token='.$token;

        $response = $this->getHttpClient()->get(
            $userUrl, $this->getRequestOptions()
        );

        $user = json_decode($response->getBody(), true);

        if (in_array('user:email', $this->scopes)) {
            $user['email'] = $this->getEmailByToken($token);
        }

        return $user;
    }

    /**
     * Get the POST fields for the token request.
     *
     * @param string $code
     *
     * @return array
     */
    protected function getTokenFields($code)
    {
        return array_add(
            parent::getTokenFields($code), 'grant_type', 'authorization_code'
        );
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected function mapUserToObject(array $user)
    {
        return (new User())->setRaw($user)->map([
            'id' => $user['sub'],
            'nickname' => $user['preferred_username'],
            'name' => Arr::get($user, 'name'),
            'email' => Arr::get($user, 'email'),
            'avatar' => $user['avatar'],               

        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Get the default options for an HTTP request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    protected function getRequestOptions()
    {
        return [
            'headers' => [
                //'Accept' => 'application/vnd.github.v3+json',
            ],
        ];
    }
}
```

Finally we should have add config values in config/services.php

```
'foo' => [
        'client_id' => 'XXXXXXXX',
        'client_secret' => 'YYYYYYYY',
        'redirect' => 'http://example.com/login/foo/callback/',
        'url' => 'https://auth.foobar.com',
    ],
```

Dont forget to update config/app.php with our new provider

```
'providers' => [
//...

 \App\Providers\MySocialServiceProvider::class

]
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [doc](https://github.com/laravel/socialite), after adding `Socialite library` and `facade` to the respective `providers` and `aliases` array in `config/app.php` file, you just need to use Socialite as

```
use Socialite;
```

But you are using

```
use Laravel\Socialite\Contracts\Factory as Socialite;
```

So, just remove above line with

```
use Socialite;
```

**updated from comment**

```
composer update
```

and

```
composer dump-autoload
```

It should work.

Comment: did you do `composer dump-autoload` ??

Comment: then try `use Laravel\Socialite\Facades\Socialite;`

Comment: I tried this also, but doesn't work: "Class Laravel\Socialite\Facades\Socialite does not exist"

Comment: I think you haven't install the package. Do you have Socialite folder in you vendor folder  ??

Comment: it works now with "use Laravel\Socialite\Facades\Socialite;" after I made composer update. Thank you a lot for your help!

Comment: If the answer help you then, please tick the answer so that it can be helpful to others in the future .

Answer (score 0):

[Official installation guide](https://github.com/laravel/socialite) says you need to use this:

```
use Socialite;
```

Instead of:

```
use Laravel\Socialite\Contracts\Factory as Socialite;
```

If it's not working, try to use:

```
use Laravel\Socialite\Facades\Socialite
```

And then use `composer dumpauto`.

Comment: Try to use `composer dumpauto`. If it will not work, try to use `use Laravel\Socialite\Facades\Socialite;`

Comment: Can you show me the line which causes an error when you're using `use Socialite` please?

Comment: it works now with "use Laravel\Socialite\Facades\Socialite;" after I made composer update. Thank you a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

"composer update" fixed this issue for me and it works with: "use Laravel\Socialite\Contracts\Factory as Socialite;"