# Lumen + Socialite - Laravel\Socialite\Contracts\Factory is not instantiable

Tags: php, laravel, lumen, laravel-socialite

I am wondering if anyone implemented a custom socialite provider for Lumen. I am trying to create a custom provider but failing to do so. The error seem redundant of similar problem found in Google search but none of them works for me. I have exhausted all of my choices.

Below is the code I am using for the provider

### `bootstrap/app.php`

```
$app->withFacades();

class_alias('Laravel\Socialite\Facades\Socialite', 'Socialite');


// socialite
$app->register(Laravel\Socialite\SocialiteServiceProvider::class);
```

### `app/Providers/AppServiceProviders.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Briovo\Providers\BriovoProvider;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        $this->registerBriovoSocialite();       
    }

    private function registerBriovoSocialite()
    {
        $briovo = $this->app->make('Laravel\Socialite\Contracts\Factory');
        /*$briovo->extend(
            'briovo',
            function ($app) use ($briovo) {
                $config = $app['config']['services.briovo'];
                return $briovo->buildProvider(BriovoProvider::class, $config);
            }
        );*/
    }

}
```

### `app/Providers/BriovoProvider.php`

```
<?php

namespace Briovo\Providers;

use Laravel\Socialite\Two\AbstractProvider;
use Laravel\Socialite\Two\ProviderInterface;
use Laravel\Socialite\Two\User;

class BriovoProvider extends AbstractProvider implements ProviderInterface {

    protected $base_url = 'http://central.dev'

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected function getAuthUrl($state)
    {
        return $this->buildAuthUrlFromBase( $base_url . '/authorize');
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected function getTokenUrl()
    {
        return $base_url . '/oauth/token';
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getAccessToken($code)
    {
        $response = $this->getHttpClient()->post($this->getTokenUrl(), [
                'form_params' => [
                'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
                'client_id' => 'client-id',
                'client_secret' => 'client-secret',
                'redirect_uri' => 'http://example.com/callback',
                'code' => $code,
            ],
        ]);

        return $this->parseAccessToken($response->getBody());
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected function getTokenFields($code)
    {
        return array_add(
            parent::getTokenFields($code), 'grant_type', 'authorization_code'
        );
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected function getUserByToken($token)
    {
        $response = $this->getHttpClient()->get( $this->base_url . '/api/me', [
            'headers' => [
                'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $token,
            ],
        ]);

        return json_decode($response->getBody(), true);
    }


}
```

### `app/Http/Controller/BriovoAuthController.php`

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Socialite;

class BriovoAuthController extends Controller
{

    protected $provider_name = 'briovo';
    public function redirectToProvider()
    {
        //return Socialite::driver($this->provider_name)->redirect();
    }

    public function handleProviderCallback()
    {
        // $user = Socialite::driver($this->provider_name)->stateless()->user();
    }

}
```

### Problem

I am getting error

```
BindingResolutionException
Target [Laravel\Socialite\Contracts\Factory] is not instantiable.
```

Problem is in the `AppServiceProvider.php` file.

The line `$briovo = $this->app->make('Laravel\Socialite\Contracts\Factory');` is failing. I have tried to call this code from `boot()` method but it had no effect.

I understand that other part of the code may not be correct right now. I can get them to work after I figure out this problem. As far as I understand I have registered the facade and the alias just fine.

### Edit 1 : Different Approach Same Result

I tried to use [socialite provider generator](https://github.com/SocialiteProviders/Generators) But I have ended up with same error!

I have followed the exact instruction for lumen but no use!

Answer (score 0):

I found this issue while implementing custom social deriver in laravel 5.5. I have implemented the custom social driver in laravel 5.4 as mentioned in the question and its working fine.

Check below StackOverflow question's answers might help you. Below one solved my issue.

[Laravel/Socialite: Class Laravel\Socialite\Contracts\Factory does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36182601/laravel-socialite-class-laravel-socialite-contracts-factory-does-not-exist/46587015#46587015)

Answer (score 0):

inside
`app/providers/AppServiceProvider.php`

paste this following

```
public function register()
{
    $this->app->singleton(\Illuminate\Contracts\Routing\ResponseFactory::class, function() {
        return new \Laravel\Lumen\Http\ResponseFactory();
    });
    $this->app->bind(\Illuminate\Contracts\Routing\UrlGenerator::class, function ($app) {
        return new \Laravel\Lumen\Routing\UrlGenerator($app);
  });
}
```